# Update view on a real minute change

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to update view every real minute change. I can't find any Notification publishers that can trigger that, so I have an idea to start timer when next minute changing, but I don't really know how to do it( I've tried this code, not seems to work:

```
.onChange(of: Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: Date())) { _ in
                print("Minute has Changed")
                
                if calendarViewModel.isTimerAlreadyPublishing {
                    print("Timer continue publishing")
                } else {
                    calendarViewModel.startTimer()
                }
            }
```

Maybe someone can say more methods how can I accomplish that goal?

Comment: TimelineView is much more efficient than timers

Comment: Yeah, but how to trigger changes every real minute

Comment: I don’t know if there is a method for that but there is an Apple workout example somewhere in the docs that updates with microseconds, depending on your use case you can probably use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with `Timer`, starting it when actual minute changes in current time zone and updating view every 60 seconds:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var currentDate = Date()
    @State var timer: Timer?

    var body: some View {
        Text("Current minute: \(currentDate.minute)")
            .onAppear {
                startMinuteTimer()
            }
        
            .onChange(of: currentDate) {_ in
                //this is called when every real minute changes in current TimeZone
            }

    }

    private func startMinuteTimer() {
        // Get the number of seconds to the next minute
        let seconds = 60 - Calendar.current.component(.second, from: .now)
        // Set the initial timer to sync with the next minute change
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(seconds)) {
            self.currentDate = Date()
            // After the first trigger, set a timer to repeat every minute
            self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 60, repeats: true) { _ in
                self.currentDate = Date()
            }
        }
    }
}

extension Date {
    var minute: Int {
        return Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: self)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Comment: Nice, Will try this thanks!

Comment: you're welcome!

Comment: It is working great, but I have a different problem, how can I stop this timer on the different view. (I have the viewModel, if it helps)

Comment: you can store timer as optional and assign it in `startMinuteTimer` function (check updated code)  and stop the timer by calling: `timer?.invalidate()` and assign back to nil:
        `timer = nil` .  I don't know where your other view is. You can invalidate timer either in .onDisappear{} on this view if you switch views, if the other view is child view you can pass timer as @Binding var. Or you can actually store timer (even with all its logic  ) in your viewmodel and share it with other views and manipulate with it

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
struct CountdownView {

    let date: Date
    @Binding var timeRemaining: Int

    var body: some View {
    Text("\(timeRemaining)")
        .onChange(of: date) {
            timeRemaining -= 1
        }
    }
}

struct TimerView { 

    @State private var timeRemaining: Int = 3
    @Binding var timerDone: Bool

    var body: some View {
    TimelineView(
        .animation(minimumInterval: 1.0, paused: timeRemaining <= 0)) { context in
            CountdownView(date: context.date, timeRemaining: $timeRemaining)
        }
        .onChange(of: timeRemaining) {
            if timeRemaining < 1 {
                timerDone = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is for instructions purposes to verify if this answer could help you.

Comment: Thanks, first time using Timeline view, hope it will also help

Comment: Hope this help you ;)